# When does it make sense to use implicit parameters in Scala, and what may be alternative scala idioms to consider?

Tags: scala, implicit

Having used a Scala library that liberally exposes the reliance on implicits to the caller, I had experienced friction around this mechanism, as Scala makes it quite hard at times to debug implicit arguments, and because there's quite a bunch of places Scala would fill in values for implicit arguments from. (I could almost relate to it as "implicits hell" at one time).

At one time in my coding, Scala "complained" an implicit value could not be matched whereas in fact there was a "collision" of implicit values each coming from a different import.

Regardless of that perceived brittleness, it may at times feel borderline to an abuse of the context design pattern.

Why does it make sense to have implicit parameters in Scala?
In what scenarios would you use them and how would you avoid trouble?

As I'm not sure the experimentation-curve and potential for other team members getting totally confused are worth it, could you possibly suggest *other scala idioms* for sharing context between a multitude of Scala functions?

This questions is not for a specific implementation at hand, hopefully it's still a good fit for this site.

Comment: Rich wrappers, extension of 3rd party libs etc. ScalaBlitz and pickling come to mind with their . par and .pickle methods, as well as lots of other libs. Of course, this imposes certain amount of responsibility upon library developers, and, what a pity, not everyone can bear that. It's like designing a collection in compliance with Scala library standards - easy to fail, but if you manage not to, the result is kinda cool.

Comment: This might be a much better fit on programmers.se

Answer (score 15):

Generally, using a common type as an implicit parameter is a bad idea.

```
def badIdea(n: Int)(implicit s: String) = s * n
```

It doesn't take much to imagine why: you'll get conflicting implicits for the same thing if anyone else adopts this policy.  Better to avoid it.

But who really wants to manually stuff in a `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` manually every time it's needed (which is practically everywhere)?

So the key is: when you have something with a specialized type, especially if it's bookkeeping that might need to be overridden manually but mostly should just do the right thing, then use implicit parameters.  (This usually covers type classes as well.)

Then what do you do if you really need a string?  Well, wrap it (at least formally--here it's a value class so in some contexts it will just pass the string around):

```
class MyWrappedString(val underlying: String) extends AnyVal {}
implicit val myString = new MyWrappedString("bird")
def decentIdea(n: Int)(implicit mws: MyWrappedString) = mws.underlying * n

scala> decentIdea(2)  // In the bush?
res14: String = birdbird
```

Or if you think some additional logic is helpful, write a wrapper that takes an extra type parameter:

```
class ImplicitWithValue[K,V](val value: V) {
  // Any extra generic logic goes here
}
object ImplicitWithValue {
  class ValuePart[K] {
    def apply[V](v: V) = new ImplicitWithValue[K,V](v)
  }
  private val genericValuePart = new ValuePart[Any]
  private def typedValuePart[K] = genericValuePart.asInstanceOf[ValuePart[K]]
  def apply[K] = typedValuePart[K]
}
```

Then you can

```
trait Marker1
implicit val implicit1 = ImplicitWithValue[Marker1]("fish")

def goodIdea(n: Int)(implicit ms: ImplicitWithValue[Marker1, String]) = ms.value * n

scala> goodIdea(3)
res17: String = fishfishfish
```

Comment: Thanks! good points! 
The problem still standing though, is the sheer amount of places an implicit can come from, and the lack of a good way to troubleshoot. It feels too brittle for a new "architected" language to leave at that state, so I hope Scala as a language will get more love to make this language feature safer to use and thus more useful.

Comment: @matt - I think the newness isn't the problem, nor will love help much.  It's a powerful feature, and as with anything that's powerful, it can be abused, and needs appropriate tools to work with.  IDEs can help by e.g. showing what precisely will get filled in in implicit values, and people can help by e.g. learning about the feature and how to take advantage of it without causing problems.